# C++ : I cannot give the input - What is wrong?

Tags: c++, input, cin

I am writing a code in C++ and one part of it is to read user's input and save it in an array.

I have written the following :

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 
 
int main() 
{  
int i; 
double C[3]; 

cout<<"Enter the coefficients:\n";
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cin >> C[i]; 
} 

return 0; 
}
```

The user is asked for the coefficients but we cannot write them. What is wrong? I don't see any mistake.

I get as output:

```
Start
Enter the coefficients:
0
Finish
```

Without being able to write anything. What do I have to change?

Comment: Where do you run this code?

Comment: What is writing the output `Start` and `Finish`?

Comment: I used the online compiler : wandbox.org @Yksisarvinen

Comment: That is automatically at the compiler at wandbox.org @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wandbox does not support interactive console. Any input has to be written upfront, before running the program, in a special window "Stdin"

[image]

If you want interactive console, you need to use a different online compiler, e.g. [Online GDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/)

Comment: In the other compiler it works!! Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Wandbox prints the `Start` message, the output of the program, the exit code of the program, and the `Finish` message.

The only output you do in your program is

```
cout<<"Enter the coefficients:\n";
```

That's it. Which means the output will be exactly as you say.

If you want more output you have to add it in your program. For example, after the input add another loop to print the values:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cout >> "C[" << i << "] = " << C[i] << '\n';
}
```

---

Also, don't forget to actually give some input in the `stdin` field of Wandbox.

Comment: Ahh ok! Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the program is running in Ubuntu

## g++ -o output output.cpp

## ./output

Enter the coefficients:
45
85
78

45 85 78